# Applescript change Date format

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-big-sur

I am hoping someone can help me out with getting this apple script to format the date into
MM/DD/YY or at least Short Date format. I am dug around a bit, but I am over my head as far as scripting and identifying variables goes.

I am running the attached script to add all my current Safari Tabs to Things (ToDoList app)

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cdzombak/b93ce2c0dca0f53a0cbcc29784882dfd/raw/2cb3b9c3f616c2c883079e9b84225fca343255e0/Safari%20Tab%20List%20to%20Things.scpt

It runs great but I would love to shorten the date

My assumption is I need to make a change in the top of the script where the variables are defined.

```
-- SET DATE STAMP
set the dateStamp to ((the current date) as string)
set noteTitle to "URL List from Safari Tabs on " & the dateStamp
```

The last line looks like the spot, but I am not sure what to change or how to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the cue: *at least **Short Date** format*

```
set dateStamp to short date string of (current date)
```

The specific string format depends on the current locale.

---

More versatile is the `date` command of the shell

```
set dateStamp to do shell script "/bin/date +%D"
```

which returns MM/DD/YY

---

Or you could use AppleScriptObjC

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set dateFormatter to current application's NSDateFormatter's new()
set dateFormatter's locale to current application's NSLocale's localeWithLocaleIdentifier:"us_EN_POSIX"
set dateFormatter's dateFormat to "MM/dd/yyyy"
set dateStamp to (dateFormatter's stringFromDate:(current date)) as text
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the part that sets the `dateStamp` variable.  To avoid any locale issues or user settings, there are a few ways to get a custom string.

A shell script can be used, although you would need to look up the `strftime` formats:

```
set dateStamp to (do shell script "date \"+%m/%d/%y\"")
```

I usually get an ISO date string (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss) and arrange the pieces as needed:

```
tell ((current date) as «class isot» as string) to set dateStamp to text 6 thru 7 & "/" & text 9 thru 10 & "/" & text 3 thru 4
```

Comment: This is perfect worked like a charm! Thank you very much!